# "Caffe2 building failed"

Tags: python, window, caffe2

When I execute the instructions "build_windows.bat" for building Caffe2, there is a huge problem.

```
"D:\caffe2\caffe2\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\caffe2\caffe2\build\caffe2\caffe2.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  D:\caffe2\caffe2\caffe2\operators\mod_op.cc(38): error C2668: "signbit": ??????????? [D:\caffe2\caffe
2\build\caffe2\caffe2.vcxproj]


"D:\caffe2\caffe2\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\caffe2\caffe2\build\modules\detectron\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.vcxproj" (default target) (7) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  D:/caffe2/caffe2/modules/detectron/softmax_focal_loss_op.cu(80): error : calling a __host__ function(
"pow<double, float> ") from a __global__ function("caffe2::_NV_ANON_NAMESPACE::SoftmaxFocalLossKernel")
 is not allowed [D:\caffe2\caffe2\build\modules\detectron\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.vcxproj]
  D:/caffe2/caffe2/modules/detectron/softmax_focal_loss_op.cu(80): error : identifier "pow<double, floa
t> " is undefined in device code [D:\caffe2\caffe2\build\modules\detectron\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.vcx
proj]
4310 Warning(s)
3 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 01:02:49.30
"Caffe2 building failed"

It seems that there are lots of errors and I hope u guys could help me!
Thanks a lot!